# Save, Share & Favourite Imageview in recyclerview

Tags: android

this codes contains a share button, download button, and a favourate button.

till now its working properly with favourate button, if i remove onClick method from ViewHolder.
I want to implement share/save button onClick share/download the Image in the ImageView in recyclerview.
Please ignore gramatical mistakes

This is my cardFragment Class.

```
        import android.content.ContentResolver;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.net.Uri;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
        import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
        import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.view.LayoutInflater;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.ViewGroup;
        import android.widget.ImageView;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        import android.widget.Toast;
        import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CardFragment extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<WonderModel> listitems = new ArrayList<>();
    RecyclerView MyRecyclerView;
    String Wonders[] = {"Chichen Itza","Christ the Redeemer","Great Wall of China","Machu Picchu","Petra","Taj Mahal","Colosseum"};
    int  Images[] = {R.drawable.chichen_itza,R.drawable.christ_the_redeemer,R.drawable.great_wall_of_china,R.drawable.machu_picchu,R.drawable.petra,R.drawable.taj_mahal,R.drawable.colosseum};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initializeList();
        getActivity().setTitle("7 Wonders of the Modern World");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_card, container, false);
        MyRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
        MyRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager MyLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        MyLayoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        if (listitems.size() > 0 & MyRecyclerView != null) {
            MyRecyclerView.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(listitems));
        }
        MyRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(MyLayoutManager);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    }

    public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyViewHolder> {
        private ArrayList<WonderModel> list;

        public MyAdapter(ArrayList<WonderModel> Data) {
            list = Data;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,int viewType) {
            // create a new view
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.recycle_items, parent, false);
            MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
            return holder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

            holder.titleTextView.setText(list.get(position).getCardName());
            holder.coverImageView.setImageResource(list.get(position).getImageResourceId());
            holder.coverImageView.setTag(list.get(position).getImageResourceId());
            holder.likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);

        }

       @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return list.size();
        }
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView titleTextView;
        public ImageView coverImageView;
        public ImageView likeImageView;
        public ImageView shareImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.titleTextView);
            coverImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.coverImageView);
            likeImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.likeImageView);
            shareImageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.shareImageView);
            likeImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {


                    int id = (int)likeImageView.getTag();
                        if( id == R.drawable.ic_like){

                            likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_liked);
                            likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_liked);

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" added to favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{

                            likeImageView.setTag(R.drawable.ic_like);
                            likeImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_like);
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),titleTextView.getText()+" removed from favourites",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        }

                }
            });



            shareImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {






                    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(ContentResolver.SCHEME_ANDROID_RESOURCE +
                            "://" + getResources().getResourcePackageName(coverImageView.getId())
                            + '/' + "drawable" + '/' + getResources().getResourceEntryName((int)coverImageView.getTag()));


                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
                    shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,imageUri);
                    shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, getResources().getText(R.string.send_to)));



                }
            });



        }
    }

    public void initializeList() {
        listitems.clear();

        for(int i =0;i<7;i++){


            WonderModel item = new WonderModel();
            item.setCardName(Wonders[i]);
            item.setImageResourceId(Images[i]);
            item.setIsfav(0);
            item.setIsturned(0);
            listitems.add(item);

        }




    }
}
```

Here is MainActivity.Java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentContainer);

        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new CardFragment();
            ;
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
                    .commit();


        }



    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your ViewHolder Constructor Like this

```
 public MyViewHolder(View v,Activity activity) {
    super(v);
this.activity = activity
/////Remaining code
```

Now you able to get the activity context in your viewholder class.
Hope it will helps you!!

Comment: Here my new issue is,when i click share button, it says file format is not supported and please help me in downloading the image from _imageview_ to gallery i.e., internal storage. favorite button is working fine.

Comment: My answer have up arrow you jus need to click and for file format not supporting i think your file is not created well can you please post your new code

Comment: No, still I have a problem with share and save button. onClicklistener method  for saving image from drawable file of recyclerview to internal storage of user.

Comment: Can u please help me with on click listener method for saving image in internal storage. I can show the method to save a single image from _R.id.image_ but  **I can't find the position of image in recycler view**.